# Probability density estimate for log relative to mean variable

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to reproduce the below graph, but with a single curve and for a different year. The paper says that Figure 1 was calculated and drawn in S-Plus, using a Gaussian kernel estimates evaluated at 100 points with a
window width of 0.6. It doesn't say how to log and center the variable.

[image]

(Black, D., & Henderson, V. (2003). Urban evolution in the USA. Journal of Economic Geography, 3(4), p348.)

After some fumbling and for some reason I cannot fathom, the following code gives a close result:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- density(temp$pop_cty/mean(temp$pop_cty))
ggplot(data.frame(d$x, d$y), aes(x=log(d$x), y=d$y)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
```

[image]

Also R tells me some negative values were omitted (because it's a log x-axis) but I don't understand where those negative values could have come from (populations are all positive).

The data I'm using is more recent but is very similar to the original paper's data so the curve should look quite similar too. As you can see my curve is too flat in the tail and too thick in the beginning (maybe because of the omitted values). How can I tweak the density function to replicate the effects of the original paper?

EDIT: After @RobertDodier's advice in the comments, I have applied log before taking density.

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- density(log(temp$pop_msa/mean(temp$pop_msa)))
ggplot(data.frame(d$x, d$y), aes(x=d$x, y=d$y)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

This results in:
[image]
Contrary to my model, the RHS of the curve is monotonic and data points are rather uniformly distributed along the x-axis.

Comment: Did you see the footnote that said "Figure 1 was calculated and drawn in S-Plus, using a Gaussian kernel estimates evaluated at 100 points with a
window width of 0.6" ? That should help.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, thank you. This is probably a very basic question but I don't know what to feed into this density function, i.e. how to center and log the variable at the same time.

Comment: "Log relative to mean <something>" probably means: find the mean of <something>, then compute the ratio of your data to that mean; the ratio will be less than 1 for smaller data and more than 1 for bigger. Now take the logarithm, you'll get negative and positive values, respectively, and 0 for data right on the mean. Now make a density of these log-ratio data using Gaussian kernels; a simpler way is to just make a histogram (you can try that just to make sure you're on the right track). Probably also worth a try to contact the authors and ask what they were doing (and also ask for their data).

Comment: @RobertDodier Very helpful thanks. My data is heavily skewed, so a histogram doesn't show much. As you can see from the above diagram, density is also very flat on the righthand side. I'm looking for a way to "raise" it like in the referenced diagram.

Comment: @syre My guess is that you have applied the log transform incorrectly. From the diagram it appears you've applied the log after estimating the density, instead of applying the log and then estimating the density. If you apply the log after estimating the density, my guess is that you have to apply a factor of (d/dx log(x)) or maybe 1/(d/dx log(x)) (one or the other, it's not clear to me which one it is without giving it more thought) to make it correct. This adjustment factor is essentially applying the so-called change of variables for probability densities; you can look that up.

Comment: @RobertDodier You are correct and rectifying the problem "raises" the RHS of the curve differentially. However, I now have a monotonically sloping curve on the RHS instead of the peaks and troughs visible in my former (albeit flattened) version of the graph and in Black & Henderson's graph. I also have uniformly distributed data points on the x-axis, instead of sparse on the LHS and denser on the RHS.